# What is the lifecycle of an IIS-hosted (http) WCF service?

Tags: wcf

I have a dependency injection container setup in my application and I'm thinking that composing the container every time a WCF service request comes in is going to be inefficient.

Can somebody explain to me, for an http/IIS hosted WCF service, what the lifecycle of the service is? If I can figure this out, I can make an educated decision on where the container is to be stored, instantiated, destroyed, etc.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your `InstanceContextMode` is **PerCall**, the service class will be created from scratch for every incoming request, and then disposed of when it's done.

If your `InstanceContextMode` is **PerSession**, the service class will be created and used to service one given client for the duration of the session (or until an "InactivityTimeout" is encountered, or an error occurs).

If your `InstanceContextMode` is **Single** (singleton), the service class will be created when the first request comes in and will stay in memory as long as requests keep coming in, as long as no error occurs and no inactivityTimeout is reached.

So, there you have it! Of course, the concurrency mode (for `PerSession` and `Single` services) will also come into play to make things just a tad more "interesting"

Comment: To set this you add a ServiceBehaviorAttribute to your service class. This is mine which matches up nicely with ninject: [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]

Answer (score 1):

As you mention that you were trying to integrate WCF service instantiation with a dependency injection container, I'd just like to say that I've had a very positive experience using the [Castle WCF Integration Facility](http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/wcf/index.html) to do just that.

It's specific to the [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/gettingstarted/index.html) dependency injection container but with it being open source you can look inside and understand some of the challenges and solutions provided.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your ServiceBehavour.
Specifically [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx).