# Self hosted WCF Service with Timer

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) example to create self hosted WCF service. Ideally I would like service to hookup with timer to check every half an hour if certain value is updated in database and if yes service would perform some task else will keep checking every half an hour. I have read it online that using timer in IIS hosted WCF is not a good idea, how about using it on self hosted wcf service? any examples?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I think a better option for you would be to create a simple console app that performs your task if the value is updated and then create a Scheduled Task in Windows that runs this console app every half hour.  That way you can let Windows manage the timing part and you just have to write the code that checks the DB and updates it if necessary.

Not sure what version of Windows you are running, but on you can get to scheduled tasks from the Control Panel.

[Create a Scheduled Task on XP](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569&ei=EoRHUbP5DIm4igLshoDADw&usg=AFQjCNHQ74G0LntAjxkCooH8PB4cDbf5cQ&bvm=bv.43828540,d.cGE)

[Create a Scheduled Task on Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/schedule-a-task)

Answer (score 0):

The reason a timer in a IIS hosted WCF service is "not a good idea" is a IIS service has a much different lifetime than a self hosted service. See this [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037985/what-is-the-lifecycle-of-an-iis-hosted-http-wcf-service) for some details and this [MSDN article for even more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx).

Basically a WCF service can be "shut down" while being hosted inside IIS if no-one has connected to it within a timeout period. If you need regular periodic maintenance like you are describing you will need to use a self hosted service and have that service start a timer up that fires every half hour in it's `OnStart()` call.